# Mathematica code to Latex

Tags: math-mode, formatting, package-options, wolfram-mathematica

I want to export my Mathematica code to Latex, so I saved the mathematica notebook as LaTeX document. Copying this latex code to overleaf, I get the attention message "\hbox too wide" and the text crosses the page borders. How could I fix this?

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{w[2]\text{:=}3*(\text{Pi}{}^{\wedge}2)/2;}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{w[3]\text{:=}4*(\text{Pi}{}^{\wedge}2);}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{k222}[\text{x$\_$},\text{t$\_$}]\text{:=}- 
\text{Sqrt}[2/3]*\text{Pi}{}^{\wedge}2*(\text{Sin} 
[\text{Pi}*x]+4*\text{Sin}[2*x*\text{Pi}]*\text{Exp} 
[I*w[2]*t]+9*\text{Sin}[3*x*\text{Pi}]*\text{Exp}[I*w[3]*t])}\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By adding new lines at appropriate places?

Comment: I personally think Mathematica code should be better put inside code environment like `lstlisting` where auto newline can be easily done.

Comment: @user202729 \newline does not work.

Comment: There should be some way. See where the command `\pmb` comes from and read its documentation to see if it supports having new lines inside.

Comment: Is your objective just to create a verbatiim image of "pure" Mathematica code, or are you looking for a way to convert the Mathematica code to LaTeX code, e.g., by replacing `\(\pmb{w[3]\text{:=}4*(\text{Pi}{}^{\wedge}2);}\)` with `$\mathbf{w}_2=4\pi^2$`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico The first one. I just want to display the Mathematica code in LaTeX.

Comment: then don't export it as latex, just paste the mathematica code into your latex document in a `verbatim` or `listings` or `minted` environment (verbatim is simplest and requires no packages, do that first)